# Prop passed to child component is undefined in created method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue.js 2.

I have a problem with passing value to the child component as a prop. I am trying to pass `card` to `card-component`.

In `card-component` I can access the prop in the `Card goes here {{card}}` section.

However when I try to access it in `created` or `mounted` methods it's `undefined`.

Parent:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                <card-component :card="place.card"></card-component>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import CostComponent from './CostComponent';
    import CardComponent from './CardComponent';

    export default {
        components: {
            CostComponent, CardComponent
        },

        props: ['id'],

        data() {
            return {
                place: []
            }
        },

        created() {
            axios.get('/api/places/' + this.id)
            .then(response => this.place = response.data);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Child:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">

                    Card goes here {{card}}

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import CardItemComponent from './CardItemComponent';

    export default {
        components: {
            CardItemComponent
        },

        props: ['card'],

        created() {
            console.log(this.card); // undefined
        },

        mounted() {
            console.log(this.card); // undefined
        },
    }
</script>
```

I did a lot of googling but none of the solutions I found have fixed my issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is purely a timing issue. Here's what happens...

1. Your parent component is created. At this time it has an empty array assigned to `place` (this is also a problem but I'll get to that later). An async request is started
2. Your parent component creates a `CardComponent` instance via its template

   ```html
   <card-component :card="place.card"></card-component>
   ```

   at this stage, `place` is still an empty array, therefore `place.card` is undefined
3. The `CardComponent` `created` hook runs, logging `undefined`
4. The `CardComponent` is mounted and its `mounted` hook runs (same logging result as `created`)
5. Your parent component is mounted
6. At some point after this, the async request resolves and changes `place` from an empty array to an object, presumably with a `card` property.
7. The new `card` property is passed down into your `CardComponent` and it reactively updates the displayed `{{ card }}` value in its template.

If you want to catch when the `card` prop data changes, you can use the `beforeUpdate` hook

```js
beforeUpdate () {
  console.log(this.card)
}
```

#### Demo

```js
Vue.component('CardComponent', {
  template: '<pre>card = {{ card }}</pre>',
  props: ['card'],
  created () {
    console.log('created:', this.card)
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log('mounted:', this.card)
  },
  beforeUpdate () {
    console.log('beforeUpdate:', this.card)
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    place: {}
  },
  created () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.place = { card: 'Ace of Spades' }
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <card-component :card="place.card" />
</div>
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

---

If `place` is meant to be an object, you should not be initialising it as an array. Also, if your `CardComponent` relies on data being present, you may want to conditionally render it.

For example

```js
data () {
  return { place: null }
}
```

and

```html
<card-component v-if="place" :card="place.card"></card-component>
```

then `CardComponent` will only be created and mounted **after** `place` has data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It explains it and it makes sense. How can I work around this? I need my child component to have access to the card property (not the empty one, but after it was updated by async request)

Comment: @kid_plama I just added an example using the `beforeUpdate` hook

Comment: thanks! Can I just check with you if I get it right? So the reason I am passing card to child component, is that in child component I need to fetch data for that card using card.id property. So instead of doing async request in created() or mounted() I should do it in beforeUpdate() or updated() methods?

Comment: @kid_plama I've added more information. Please see the note at the end of my answer

Comment: thanks, rendering the component with `v-if`, or using `beforeUpdate` | `update` methods solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `props: true` in the router file. It is a simple solution but many of us forget this.

```
{
  path: '/path-to',
  name: 'Name To',
  component: Component,
  props: true
}
```