# Getting undefined in console.log but vue console shows the values correct

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vue and I am not being able to console log this.productVal.name, only getting undefined, but vue console extension shows that I have all the values correctly.
[image: here]

```
export default {
  props: ['productVal'],
  created() {
    console.log(this.productVal.name);
  },
}
```

This is how I am going to child component

```
<child-product v-if="product" :product-val="product"></child-product>
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974846/prop-passed-to-child-component-is-undefined-in-created-method

Comment: Thanks, found it myself. beforeUpdate actually worked, but v-if from parent hasnt worked, I tried that

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure cause of lack of information, but if its a child component, go to the parent one and add `v-if="productVal"` to the child component tag. The reason of this might be thing that when you creating this component your prop value is not initialized yet, so you cannot read the `name` of `productVal` prop value, so you are getting undefined.

Example

You probably have something like this in your parent component:

```
<template>
   <child-component :product-val="productVal">
</template>
```

so change this to:

```
<template>
   <child-component v-if="productVal" :product-val="productVal">
</template>
```

and it should work properly.

Comment: I did it like this

`<child-product v-if="product" :product-val="product"></child-product>`

Comment: Did it work? If not, could you please update post about more information? e.g. What is undefined? How does parent component looks like (including passing prop)?

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice I was using an object for checking in v-if while going to child component, that doesnt work. SO I tried this way and it worked. `product.name` instead of `product`

```
<child-product v-if="product.name" :product-val="product"></child-product>
```

hope it helps someone else in the future while debugging.